# How to get the date of a specific day in every month and year?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Just want to get the date of Monday, Wednesday and Saturday of every month in the years.
i tried to managed it this way;

```
DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
int deltaMonday = DayOfWeek.Monday - today.DayOfWeek;
var monday = today.AddDays(deltaMonday);


int deltaWednesday = DayOfWeek.Wednesday - today.DayOfWeek;
var wednesday = today.AddDays(deltaWednesday);

int deltaSaturday = DayOfWeek.Saturday - today.DayOfWeek;
var saturday = today.AddDays(deltaSaturday);
```

But i want to show the next (e.g) monday date if this (week) monday is passed away and similarly for wednesday and saturday too. If the (current) month is passed away, then next month days should be displayed. Is there any shorter way to get or change my code?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. You need to get all mondays, Wednesdays,  Saturdays in a year?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, but if this week monday is passed away, then next week days should be displayed

Comment: Who's "today" are you starting with?  It might be Monday morning in UTC, but Sunday night in the USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  -

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
 int deltaMonday = DayOfWeek.Monday - today.DayOfWeek;
 var monday = today.AddDays(deltaMonday += deltaMonday < 0 ? 7 : 0);

 int deltaWednesday = DayOfWeek.Wednesday - today.DayOfWeek;
 var wednesday = today.AddDays(deltaWednesday += deltaWednesday < 0 ? 7 : 0);

 int deltaSaturday = DayOfWeek.Saturday - today.DayOfWeek;
 var saturday = today.AddDays(deltaSaturday += deltaSaturday < 0 ? 7 : 0);
```

In short, if the day is passed away, that is the difference is negative, then just add 7 days to it.

Do similar things if you need to check for months.

Comment: this works for the day but if the current month is passed away and how about the next year i-e if current year is passed away

Comment: just check whether the month and year of current date is less or greater than the target year. Could you mention the actual scenario?. I might help you better after knowing that.

Comment: Suppose this month is june and this month is passed away. Next is july, then the code should get the july's days i.e Monday Wednesday, and Saturday. Does `DateTime.UtcNow` will work for next month too ?

Comment: Yes, this will always get current month, so when you are in july it will return july, when you are in august, it will show august. but also remember that `DateTime.UtcNow` gives you GMT values, if you want to get localized date time then use `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
 Public DateTime GetNextWeekday(DayOfWeek day)
 {
     DateTime result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
     while( result.DayOfWeek != day )
          result = result.AddDays(1);
     return result;
 }

 DateTime deltaMonday=GetNextWeekday(1)
 DateTime deltaWednesday=GetNextWeekday(3)
 DateTime deltaSaturday=GetNextWeekday(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many days ahead you need to look, you could use linq. The code below finds all Monday, Wednesday and Saturday in the next 100 days:

```
var daysAhead = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
var dates = daysAhead.Select (a => DateTime.Today.AddDays(a))
                         .Where (a => a.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ||
                                      a.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday ||
                                      a.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ).ToList();
```

Comment: i need this for lifetime, it should continuously change the days automatically